# Overriding Python pdb to show relative paths instead of absolute?

Tags: python, pdb

When stepping ('s') through a Python based plugin with pdb the absolute path of the current file is shown. In this particular case the absolute path is *really* long, so I would like pdb to show either a relative or partial path instead.

Any pointers or suggestions on where I should look? I thought maybe I didn't have the current directory set correctly, but it appears to always wants to show the absolute path. Do I need to subclass pdb? Thanks!

Comment: The debugger uses the full path on purpose to prevent the confussion of files, like different versions of a package.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. In this case though it really presents a usability problem because the absolute file paths wrap around onto, at times, 3 different lines. Given what I'm working on having duplicate filenames isn't even a concern so I'm looking for how to approach overriding the default behavior.